# how to do OUTPUT in arduino cpp file

Tags: arduino-c++

I am trying to figure out how to modularize my program. I probably should not be, since I am only beginner trying to write code for Arduino. BUT, putting it all in one file is driving me batty.

I have an .INO file. I can make it compile with pinMode and digitalWrite commands in it. If I move that code to a .CPP file, I get errors that OUTPUT, HIGH, LOW, INPUT_PULLUP are not declared in this scope. I have tried including files I thought might contain the definitions but nothing is working.
How do I make this work?

Comment: You can add .ino files to IDE.

Comment: a .cpp file requires `#include <arduino.h>`

Answer (score 0):

I ADDED THIS TO THE FILES AND IT APPEARS TO WORK
#include <arduino.h>